# Xpath PHP: How to not get textContent from span inside div?

Tags: php, html, xpath

I have the following html code

```
    <div id="brandModel">
        Jeep Grand Cherokee,
        <span class="red">529.80&nbsp;EUR</span>
    </div>
```

The following PHP/Xpath works, but also returns the text inside span.

`$xPathcarName = $xpath->query( "//div[@id='brandModel']" );
echo $xPathcarName->item(0)->textContent\r\n";`

Output: 
`Jeep Grand Cherokee,
529.80┬áEUR`

I only want the textContent inside the div, not inside the span. Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perfectly possible.

```
$xPathcarName = $xpath->query( "//div[@id='brandModel']" );
echo $xPathcarName->item(0)->firstChild->textContent . "\r\n";
```

Remember that in a DOMDocument loaded as XML/XHTML, text is actually a DOMText node. You can see this by looping through the children of your div.